# On click change icons on the rest items - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Accordion code:

```
<div v-b-toggle="'accordion' + number" class="accordion-header" @click="isActive = !isActive">
  <h4><slot/></h4>
  <i class="fas" :class="isActive ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus'"></i>
</div>
```

Data:

```
data () {
  return {
    isActive: false
  }
}
```

When i click on one question, it changes question's icon to minus, if i click again, then it changes to plus. The problem comes out when i click on one question, then click on another question, previous question has minus icon, though it's closed:

[image]

Comment: The error is not in this code. You should elaborate your code example

Comment: It's not about the errors here, it's a working code. Question is - how to make previously clicked accordion items to have plus icon, when i open a new item without closing a previous one (clicking i mean).